# Missing or invalid PGP blocking updates on Elementary OS

Tags: updates, ubuntu

Seem to have broken the updates somehow.  This may have happened after I tried a manual install of a package; I thought only a single package would need to be managed, but perhaps this causes the error.

End result, updates not working.

```
W: GPG error: http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release: 
The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG BF36996C4E1F8A59 Launchpad PPA for elementary OS team
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I located the gpg file at the repository and tried

```
curl http://http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/Release.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Can anyone help on this one please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing; posted message, few mins later **Updates available** popped up, 121 updates installed with no issue.

Perhaps a daemon fixed it.  ;-)